# Equivalent of "sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)" in Windows

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, porting

I'm trying to port my program from Linux to Windows and I'm having trouble with `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)`. From what I researched, the equivalent of `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` in Windows is `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` but Visual Studio is complaining about this. Does anyone know any command/function that is equivalent to `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` in Windows?

Comment: Equivalent for what purpose? `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` is only meaningful for interpreting the results of the `times()` function and perhaps a few other related things.

Comment: How does VS complain?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably replace it by either [`QueryPerformanceFrequency()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`GetProcessTimes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx).

[CLOCKS_PER_SEC](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/) is only useful when used in conjunction with [`clock()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/), which for most purposes is quite useless since it returns the processor time consumed by the program, not the real time.

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7830496/1198654).